# SQL bad attribute (column) names

Tags: mysql, database, database-schema

I've created table in MySQL database with the query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `CREW` (
`ID` INT NOT NULL,
`CALL` VARCHAR(45) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`));
```

And it did work perfectly, but when I tried to:

```
INSERT INTO CREW (ID, CALL) VALUES (0, 'None');
```

I've got `ERROR 1064`. What are the other **bad names** for attributes that we should avoid?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html ?

Comment: maybe the 'call' attribute? try changing it's name

Comment: I'm not expert in different DBMS's - so it would be nice to have some techniqe for attribute naming to prevent collisions with reserved words (existining or which-may-appear) in different DBMS's (not only in MySQL but e.g. in Derby as well)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't use reserved words for column names. MySQL list here: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html. Multi-db list here: https://www.drupal.org/node/141051
2. If you want your SQL to be compatible with other databases, you should use snake_case

Comment: Yep, right. I thought about it as a Relation development. It's what I wished to know. But whait, why _snake_case_ not _CamelCase_?

Comment: _Relation development_ - I mean how to correctly set up attribute names e.g. in MySQL Workbench in order to have _good_ auto-generated queries.

Comment: @UmbraAeternitatis due to oddities in other databases (*cough* postgres) snake_case is the only cross-database alternative

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like you did it in your create statement.
Sourround the attribute names and the table names with backticks:

```
INSERT INTO `CREW` (`ID`, `CALL`) VALUES (0, 'None');
```

If you do it always like this, you don't need to avoid any names.

Comment: Yep, this one does work. But this does not work with
`ALTER TABLE \`CREW\` RENAME COLUMN \`CALL\` TO \`CALLSIGN\`;`

Comment: MySQL backticks-hack may cause incompatibilities with other DBMSs if I generate queries for them.

Answer (score 0):

One of the column name is 'CALL' in your CREW table. The [CALL statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/call.html) used to invoke a stored procedure. So when you are executing

```
INSERT INTO CREW (ID, CALL) VALUES (0, 'None');
```

Mysql understand that you are some how trying to execute a stored procedure. So you need to Surround the attribute names with back-ticks

```
INSERT INTO CREW ('ID', 'CALL') VALUES (0, 'None');
```

Comment: And one more thing - is this trick with _backticks_ DBMS independent?

Comment: No,backticks is not DBMS independent.backticks is not ANSI-SQL compliant, for example they do not work in SQL Server.

Comment: So we just have to avoid reserved words as attribute names in order to make _good_ queries to databases, don't we?

Comment: Yes.You are correct.It is often recommended to avoid using reserved keywords as column or table identifiers when possible to avoid the quoting issue.